# Why do ambient declarations use namespace and module?

Tags: module, typescript

I noticed that many ambient declaration files `declare` a `namespace` *and* a `module` that merely exports the namespace, usually using some gymnastics that I don't really understand. For example, in [`react.d.ts`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/react/react.d.ts) you see this:

```
declare namespace __React {

    ... entire API of the react library ...

}

declare module "react" {
    export = __React;
}
```

1. Why both a `namespace` and a `module`? Why not just declare the module with the library API inside it?
2. Why is the namespace called `__React` and not simply `React`? That seems like a rather awkward "don't use me" name, yet IntelliJ IDEA has imported this all over my source code and it seems to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This pattern is used to support [UMD libraries](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2014/what-is-amd-commonjs-and-umd/).

These libraries generally put something into the global scope if they're loaded through a `<script ...>` tag, but return something to a module loader if invoked via a module system like RequireJS, CommonJS, or SystemJS.

In TypeScript, this means that if you `import` the module called `'react'`, you should get the same type as if you reference the global identifier `React`.

Most definition files simply write their .d.ts files such that the module shape and the global variable are always both present; the React authors didn't like that you could accidently refer to the global `React` if you were using a module loader (in which case the global wouldn't actually be there) so they separated out the declaration into `__React`, a separate .d.ts file that declared a global called `React`, and a module declaration for `"react"`.

Comment: Thanks, that was a really clear explanation and it all makes sense now! What's interesting (annoying) is that IntelliJ IDEA always wants to `import Component = __React.Component` instead of `import {Component} from "react"` even though I'm using `module: commonjs`. For interfaces, like `import MouseEventHandler = _React.MouseEventHandler` it works, I guess because the interface isn't a referenced symbol in the compiled JS, but for other things I get `Can't find variable: __React`. I guess the IDE could be a bit smarter here.